# How to implement a graph from an input text file in python?

Tags: python, graph, breadth-first-search, adjacency-list

I have an input file of the format:

```
Stuttgart Nuremberg 207
Nuremberg Munich 171
Manchester Birmingham 84
Birmingham Bristol 85
Birmingham London 117
END OF INPUT
```

I want to apply brute force algorithm to find shortest path (distance) between two cities for which I need to convert the text to graph. Again, the graph needs to be made dynamically, should work for this or any other input file with the same format.

EDIT:: Your answer helped but it is counting the line "END OF INPUT" So I modified the code as :

I tried to add while loop like this:

```
      Graph = {}
      filename = open('Input1.txt', 'r')
      for line in filename:
          while line != "END OF INPUT" :
              node1, node2, d = line.split()
              Graph.setdefault(node1, []).append((node2, d))
              Graph.setdefault(node2, []).append((node1, d))  # Undirected
```

graph

But then it is working only for first two lines. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to represent a Graph but one of the simplest is a dictionary of nodes to list of edges, e.g.:

```
{
  'Stuttgart': [('Nuremberg', 207)],
  'Nuremberg': [('Munich', 171)],
  'Manchester': [('Birmingham', 84)],
  'Birmingham': [('Bristol', 85), ('London', 117)]
}
```

If this is an undirected graph you will need to add the inverse of the edges, e.g.:

```
  'Nuremberg': [('Stuttgart', 207), ('Munich', 171)],
```

This should be a pretty easy structure to work with for most graph algorithms.
For your problem, you will need to decide if you can back track (visit a node more than once) and if your graph is fully connected (which your example data isn't), to decide on the appropriate algorithm.

You can build the graph from your file (strawman):

```
graph = {}   # or use defaultdict(list)
with open('<filename>', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
         n1, n2, d = l.split()
         graph.setdefault(n1, []).append((n2, d))
         graph.setdefault(n2, []).append((n1, d))  # Undirected graph
```

There are many libraries that implement graph algorithms, check out networkx: https://networkx.github.io/ to see if this has what you need.

Comment: `n1, n2, d = l.split()` will not work if you have a line like "New York Mexico City 987"

Comment: Without a separator this will be a difficult line to split automatically. The separator could be anything, e.g. comma `l.split(',')` or two spaces or a tab, etc. Without a separator you will need a list of valid city names and look to match them in the line.

Answer (score 0):

For the part after edit where it is mentioned that only first two lines are getting printed of the text file.

Change the condition of the while loop

while "END OF INPUT" not in line